# how to add a custom button that can used clicked event in django admin.py

Tags: python, django

I have a model which named Record, the model have the source code info.
Now, I want add a button in the admin site.
Current django admin.py code like:

```
@admin.register(Record)
class ControlRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["file_path", "go_to_src_code", "func_info", "line"]
    search_fields = ['file_path', 'func_info']
    list_filter = ['severity', 'is_misinformation']
    actions = [jump_to_src_code]

    def go_to_src_code(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<button onclick= "" >Go</button>'
        )

    go_to_src_code.short_description = "GoToSrcCode"
```

I want to specify the specified method after clicking the button, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the next action.

## You want to call js function on the list view:

```
def jump_to_src_code(*args, **kwargs):
    print('it works in python')

@admin.register(Record)
class ControlRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["file_path", "go_to_src_code", "func_info", "line"]
    search_fields = ['file_path', 'func_info']
    # list_filter = ['severity', 'is_misinformation']
    actions = [jump_to_src_code]

    class Media:
        js = ('myjs.js')

    def go_to_src_code(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<button onclick= "alert(\'it works in js\'); // call function from myjs.js" >Go</button>')
    go_to_src_code.short_description = "GoToSrcCode"
```

by click you start the js:
[image: start js]

## You want call the special admin action:

```
def jump_to_src_code(*args, **kwargs):
    print('it works in python')

@admin.register(Record)
class ControlRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["file_path", "go_to_src_code", "func_info", "line"]
    search_fields = ['file_path', 'func_info']
    # list_filter = ['severity', 'is_misinformation']
    actions = [jump_to_src_code]

    # class Media:
        # js = ('myjs.js')

    def go_to_src_code(self, obj):
        action_name = 'jump_to_src_code'
        action_index_in_action_list = '1'
        return mark_safe(f"""
            <input type="hidden" name="_selected_action" value="{obj.id}">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{action_name}">
            <button type="submit" name="index" value="{action_index_in_action_list}">Go</button>"""
            )
    go_to_src_code.short_description = "GoToSrcCode"
```

this gives you call your action function in python.

[image]

thanks for comments:
ia am agree, that not all works in example before, for admin action call.
i've made some improvements:

```
def go_to_src_code(self, obj):
    action_name = 'jump_to_src_code'
    action_index_in_action_list = '1'
    return mark_safe(f"""
        <label class="your_style">Go
        <input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.disabled=false;this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.disabled=false;this.form.submit()" value="{obj.id}" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" disabled name="action" value="{action_name}">
        <input type="hidden" disabled name="index" value="{action_index_in_action_list}">
        </label>"""
        )
```

Why we need that:

1. inputs for action ("index", "action") - they should be disabled before. Otherwise other action not works.
2. input for obj.pk ("_selected_action") - this should be checkbox. Otherwise browser send list of objects.pk.

I don't like this improvement, in my opinion here should be new view with redirect and button with "formaction" attribute. But it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really solved one of my big problems

Comment: Hi man, I tried this implementation, but now there is a problem: Clicking on any one always returns to the last one obj.id

Comment: i add in example small improvements.

Comment: Thanks reply, I'll try this method again.  Thanks again.

Comment: It works well, although I don't know the principle. I know nothing about the front end.